# Show that $x_1' = x_2, \space x_2' = -2x_1 + x_2(2-5x_1^2 - 3x_2^2)$ has a bounded solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

> Consider the dynamical system :
>   $$x_1' = x_2, \space \space x_2' = -2x_1 + x_2(2-5x_1^2 - 3x_2^2)$$
>   where $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R$. Using the functional $V(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{2} x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} x_2^2$, prove that for any given inital value, the initial value problem has a bounded solution.

**Attempt :**

Take the derivative over the solution curves for the given functional, which is :

$$\dot{V}(x_1,x_2) = -x_1x_2 + x_2^2(2-5x_1^2-3x_2^2)$$

I will try "increase" this expression via inequalities (which is a standard way of handling such problems), so that I can provide a compact form with $V(x_1,x_2)$ in expressions which we know it's positive :

$$\dot{V}(x_1,x_2)\leq-x_1x_2 + x_2^2(2-3x_1^2-3x_2^2)\leq\frac{1}{2}x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}x_2^2 + x_2^2(2-x_1^2 - x_2^2)$$

Now, I have reduced the coefficients inside the parenthesis, since $x_1^2,x_2^2 \geq0$ which means that a smaller coefficient leads to a bigger quality. The inequality derived for the expression at front is a simple application of $(x_1+x_2)^2 \geq 0$.

However, I cannot seem how I should continue from now on, since that $x_2^2$ in front of the parenthesis is bugging me and I do not know how to convert it while keeping the inequality in a form that would produce an expression of $V$.

Any tips ?

Comment: If $\dot{V} \leqslant 0$ holds everywhere, the origin would be asymptotically Lyapunov stable equilibrium. But it's not true, it's unstable focus. Actually you have to split your analysis of $\dot{V}$ into two separate cases.

Comment: @Evgeny Not interested for stability in this case but just showing that the solutions would be bounded which just relies into  forming an inequality that would involve an expression like $V^k(x)(R-V^n(x))$. Then you'd just take a restriction for $V(x)$ and it would be bounded !

Comment: @Evgeny The fact that every trajectory is repelled though, shouldn't lead to the solutions being not bounded ?

Comment: Not really. It seems that there is an attracting limit cycle that surrounds the origin. What is repelled from the origin goes on to this limit cycle. The trajectories outside of the limit cycle go to it too. The only reason why I accentuated this is because you have to prove that $\dot{V} \leqslant 0$ holds for all points outside of some circle $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$ and in some other places this inequality doesn't really hold (near the origin, for example). I thought this observation can help you get better estimates, but probably you already had this in mind.

Comment: Did your textbook tell you to consider this function $V$, or did you make a typo?

Comment: @Did It's an exams problem, so this is exactly the functional $V$ that we should use. I accepted the answer below though since it's interesting and works some things around another way. I added a comment elaborating for the method I used but maybe through a weird inequality it could be shown that an $R\geq 2/3$ would be needed.

Comment: It seems the $x_1x_2$ term in $\dot V$ is really ruining things since it dominates $x_2^2$ when $|x_1|$ is much larger than $|x_2|$, so what we would have here is an example of a bad exam problem.

Comment: @Did Yeah indeed. Because even when you apply that : $$-x_1x_2 \leq \frac{1}{2} x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} x_2^2 = V$$ you still get the issue of $x_2^2$ which you cannot work around simply by increasing it to $$x_1^2+x_2^2$$ exactly because the sign of the parenthesis multiplied is not strict. I was trying to work around a solution to this problem thinking of some inequality but it seems like it's exactly what you mentioned (your contribution has been really interesting and good).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functional $V$ is ill-adapted to this system. On the other hand, a one-line computation shows that $$W(x_1,x_2)=2x_1^2+x_2^2$$ is such that $\dot W(x_1,x_2)$ has the sign of $$Z(x_1,x_2)=2-5x_1^2-3x_2^2$$ Thus $\dot W\leqslant0$ on the set $\{W\geqslant3\}\subset\{Z\leqslant0\}$ and $\dot W\geqslant0$ on the set $\left\{W\leqslant\frac23\right\}\subset\{Z\geqslant0\}$.

This shows that every solution starting from $(x_1,x_2)\ne(0,0)$ ends in the annulus $$\left\{\tfrac23\leqslant W\leqslant3\right\}$$ which implies the desired boundedness result. The behaviour we just described is confirmed by the rough figure below.

[image]

Comment: Really nice plot there ! It shows exactly the effect of $θ' = -1$ which is interesting to see ! The selection of $W$ really comes in hand in this particular example, I don't know why the exercise implies another functional which makes our life tougher. Truth is though, it's interesting to see that the sign of the expression acts on the annulus. I guess it could be shown in my elaboration too that if you implied $ \geq \dots + (x_1^2 +x_2^2)(2-5x_1^2 - 3x_2^2)$ then you'd need to specify the sign of the parentheses which would lead to the same annulus as yours ! Great stuff again.